# Compatibility numpy 1.7 vs numpy 1.8

Tags: python, numpy

Hi is there a compatibility issue with numpy 1.7 and 1.8?
I am getting error with a npy that was created using python 2.7 and numpy 1.7. Now I use python 3.4 and numpy 1.8

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\format.py", line 334, in read_array_header_1_0
    d = safe_eval(header)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\utils.py", line 1128, in safe_eval
    ast = compiler.parse(source, mode="eval")
  File "C:\Python34\lib\ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    {'descr': '<f8', 'fortran_order': False, 'shape': (51L,), }
                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the value of shape key. In python 3 you can't add L after the declaration.

```
martin@martin-desktop:~$ python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 13:08:17) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 3
3
>>> 3L
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    3L
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

[PEP 237](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237), first drafted in 2001, introduced an effort to remove the distinction between `int` and `long` integers. The work was completed in a three-phased approach spanning Python 2.2 through 2.4. Python 3.0 added a final step by officially removing the **long()** type and `long` literals (e.g., `123456789L`).

In places where you would use **long()**, **int()** is the replacement and it will store the value in the correct internal representation.

In places where you used the `L` suffix to produce `long` literals, removal of the L is necessary, otherwise a **SyntaxError** will be raised.

http://docs.pythonsprints.com/python3_porting/py-porting.html#long-integers